# how to run and stop a bash script in a init.d process?

Tags: bash, shell, service, process, init

i have a process script and i want it to run and stop (if already running) a bash script.

I've tried `pkill -x test` but it doesn't seem to work. in any case i believe i need a `if` statement, to see if `test.sh` is running..

EDIT: in the stop i added `for i in`ps ax | grep 'test' | awk '{print $1}'`; do kill -9 $i; done`

that seems to fix it.. need to do some more testing

here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

prog="test"
NEWLINE=$'\n'

start() {
    STR=$"Starting $prog ${NEWLINE}"
    echo "$STR"

    /var/www/html/test.sh
    # code to start app comes here
    # example: daemon program_name &
}

stop() {
    STR=$"Stopping $prog ${NEWLINE}"
    echo "$STR"

    pkill -x test
    # code to stop app comes here
    # example: killproc program_name
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        ${0} stop
        sleep 1
        ${0} start
        ;;
    status)
        ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

any ideas?

Comment: `test` does not exactly match `test.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if the script test.sh puts a file in /var/run with it's pid. You can use the variable $$ for that.
Then you could look for for the process with the pid with ps and grep in the init script and killing it easy.